# Use custom widgets kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, button, kivy

I'm trying to build a kivy app using some custom widgets.  However whenever I try to use them they never work with my layout.  Using a normal button:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class RootWidget(Widget):pass

class myApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global rw
        rw  = RootWidget()
        return rw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()

#:kivy 1.8.0

<RootWidget>:

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        Button:
            id: abut
            text: "Custom Button"
```

This works as expected, my Button basically takes up the entire window.  However when I try replacing the Button with my custom button

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class MyWidget(Widget):

     pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

     def on_touch_down(self, touch):
         if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             self.pressed = touch.pos
             return True
         return super(MyWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

     def on_pressed(self, instance, pos):
         print ('pressed at {pos}'.format(pos=pos))

class RootWidget(Widget):pass

class someApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global rw
        rw  = RootWidget()
        return rw

if __name__ == '__main__':
    someApp().run()

#:kivy 1.8.0

<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10

        Button:
            id: abut
            text: "Custom Button"        

<RootWidget>:

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 10
        padding: 10

        MyWidget:
```

it only appears in the bottom left-hand corner of the window and doesn't behave like a button.  What am I missing?

Furthermore, is it even necessary to create a custom button this way?  The kivy tutorials used this sort of method to make their custom button but can't I just do something like this

```
Button:
    on_press: root.do_action()
```

to make each button behave differently?

Comment: yes you can just do the second method ... (tbh I like to avoid the .kv language as much as possible and implement most of this stuff in python directly)

Comment: @JoranBeasley why do you avoid kvlang?

Comment: I just have a natural aversion to descriptive languages in general (plus before 1.8 there was some memory leaks with circular refs in .kv files)  I have a better understanding of whats happening when I just sublclass widget in python and build up my stuff that way

Comment: all that said imho Kivy is THE WAY to do cross platform gui stuff (especially targeting tablets and phones)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your actual problem is that although your `MyWidget` is placed in a `BoxLayout` in the kv file, its child `BoxLayout` does *not* have its size set to the `MyWidget` size, and therefore just maintains the default size and position of `(100, 100)` in the bottom left of the screen.

You can fix this by giving it the extra `size: root.size` rule as you did within the `<RootWidget>` rule, or actually normally it's easier to just use a BoxLayout (i.e. subclass `BoxLayout` instead of `Widget`) which of course gives you the automatic resizing/positioning for free.

Also, as Joran said, if you just want to do something when the button is pressed you can use the second method...that's what you're intended to do! I don't know what example you are looking at, but you wouldn't normally need a complex arrangement like yours.

You might also be interested to know that in the most recent release (1.8) the button behavior has been abstracted to a `ButtonBehavior` class that handles detecting touches and dispatching `on_press` etc. appropriately. The Behavior isn't a widget, so you can subclass it with any other widget to make anything into a button!