# Kivy-Add custom widget definded in py file via kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I have a custom button. I cannot put it on screen via kv file. I studied a lot topics. No useful info can find. Here is a simple example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<MyGrid>:
    Button
        text: 'hello'
''')

class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    pass

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

Note that the Button in this kv file is native Kivy button. I run this code, I can see this button on screen. But now I have a custom Button:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 1.11.0

<MyGrid>:
    customButton:
''')

class MyGrid(BoxLayout):
    pass

class customButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.text = 'hi'
        super(Button, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

I run this code, I cannot see this customButton on screen. Note that the custom widget is complex. I have to define it in py file. For example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

Building this layout need for loop. I cannot find a way to build it in kv file. So I define it in Py file. But if I define it in py file, I cannot work with it in kv file.

Question 1: What's wrong with the second code?

Question 2: If I can't make it work, can I achieve the third code in kvlang(in kv file not in python)?

I am new to Kivy, hope someone can help.

Comment: it works fine for me

Comment: hi @infinityTM , the second code works on your machine?  Cannot believe that

Comment: it just created a lot of buttons

Comment: I shall show that as an answer

Comment: What are you trying for? scrool view for buttons?

Comment: hi @InfinityTM , I am trying to make the second code works.  Sorry for my English, it didn't make my thoughts clear.  I'll adjust it.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it

Comment: hi @InfinityTM , I just find the trick. Refer this [Page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798202/12752239): The name of the custom widget customButton need to be changed to CustomButton. The first character should be in upper case.

Comment: ok. so the question is done?

Comment: i'll add that to the answer so that the question can be closed

Comment: Check now the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the code on Kivy `v1.11.1` , Python `v3.7.5`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class DropApp(App):
    def build(self):

        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10)
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DropApp().run()
```

The output is:

[image: output]

If this is the output you require, try running:

```
pip install --upgrade kivy
```

---

For the second code, python is case-sensitive. So instead of `customButton`, use `CustomButton`.

---

If you want to do the 3rd code using .kv file, here is an example:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''

<ExampleRV>:

    viewclass: 'Button'

    RecycleBoxLayout:

        size_hint_y: None

        height: self.minimum_height

        orientation: 'vertical'

''')

class ExampleRV(RecycleView):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(ExampleRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(20)]

class RecycleApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return ExampleRV()

RecycleApp().run()
```

For reference, go [HERE](https://likegeeks.com/kivy-tutorial/).

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! BTW, can I specify the ranger number in kv file?  It's 20 in your RecycleApp code. Can I have a way to set it in kv, like "rangeNumber: 20"?

Comment: i dont think so, i'll check it